# How do I get a mysqli_result when the mysqli result instance is wrapped in a third-party class?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Usually when I use mysqli, my queries are as following:

```
$query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM .........");
$data = $mysql->fetch_assoc();
```

However, that's not possible using

```
$mQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE `order_id` = $orderid");
while($mData = $mQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
...
}
```

How can I convert this into a functional code?

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::fetch_assoc()

Comment: It's possible . If a db->query(...) fails $mQuery == NULL. Now you can't use `while($mData = $mQuery->fetch_assoc())` !! As I said , you have to test for `$mQuery != NULL` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference: In the first example you are calling methods on the `$mysql` object, so in the second example you should do the same:

```
$mQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE `order_id` = $orderid");
while($mData = $this->db->fetch_assoc()) {
  //           ^^^^^^^^^ The same object of which you called the query method
  ...
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB::fetch_assoc()

Comment: @Chriham If you get that here, you will have gotten that in your first example as well as they are exactly the same.

Comment: @jeroen : I never see that without the use of `$mQuery` : As you can clear see : array mysqli_result::fetch_assoc ( void ). `fetch_assoc` is part of the mysqli_result class. Not part of `mysqli — The mysqli class` ! `$mQuery` is a `mysqli_result` .

Comment: The broader point is that you are using some kind of abstraction layer on top of MySQLi, and now you're returning an instance of the class "DB" (whatever *THAT( is), instead of returning the mysqli_result instance.

Answer (score 1):

The function behind $this->db->query needs to return a mysqli_result instance instead of returning a stdClass.

Comment: Not true : `$this->db->query needs to return the mysqli instance` true : needs to return `mysqli_result` instance.

Comment: Thanks @moskito-x for correcting me - I don't use MySQLi, forgot the API off-hand. I should have checked it before posting.